# How to change App Profiles Page to match changed Namespace

Tags: namespaces, facebook-page, facebook-apps

We recently changed the Namespace for our canvas app from 'karmakorn' to 'karmalyze' to get ready for an alpha release.

The Facebook platform correctly points to http://apps.facebook.com/karmalyze for the canvas, but continues to point to http://www.facebook.com/KarmaKorn for the app profiles page.

We don't see anyplace to edit this. Is it a Facebook bug? Is there some trick we can do to trigger the correct setting?

Answer (score 0):

The app namespace and the app's profile page URL are completely separate. At some point you set your page's "username" to be KarmaKorn by going to facebook.com/usernames while logged in as an administrator of the page (a developer of the app). The app's namespace is set completely separately in the Developer app.

Officially there is no way to change or transfer your Facebook page's username. You could make a second page at the URL you want and set up some links to direct users from one of those pages to the other (or maintain both of them in tandem).

Comment: Vin, thanks for this helpful clarification. We have 200+ people who have liked our KarmaKorn app profile page, so we would like to keep that one. If we set up a karmalyze general page, how and where do we set up the links to seamlessly forward that to the KarmaKorn page?

Comment: I wouldn't say it could ever be "seamless", but you can basically edit the Page Info to include links, post them frequently to the wall, and/or add an App Tab that lets you customize a landing page to include links (such as a Static HTML tab).